How to detect any process privilege changed programmatically?
SeDebugPrivilege is a sensitive privilege. Therefore, I want to write a tool to detect when a process enables SeDebugPrivilege in a user mode program or kernel mode driver.
But I can't find any callback function to approach it.
I know Windows provide the event id 4703 to audit the privileges being changed. But there are too many 4703 events that occur and increase the size of the log volume. ( 4703 Event not only audit for the SeDebugPrivilege )
Is there any method that could programmatically detect the process privilege being changed just like the Audit Event 4703?
On the other hand, do I need to use a hook on the AdjustTokenPrivileges API?

Token privilege set not changed. But privilege can be in enabled or disabled state.  We can on or off it in token. But can not add it to token, if it not initially exist here. Also code can open another process/thread token and impersonate with it. If have impersonate privilege of course. All this operations not logged. You can simply open process , or threads tokens, and query it - are some privileges enabled or disabled.

There is no direct way in documentation. For Windows Event Log, you may also have a look at https://github.com/repnz/etw-providers-docs/tree/master.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT thanks!!  Because i think the audit event 4703 generated by ETW in someware on OS  ( maybe the AdjustTokenPrivileges code will send audit event etw log ),  maybe MS will provide the callback method api to let us listen the changed.
